# How do I SSH to an Azure VM and run a program on it forever after shutting off my local machine?

Tags: azure, ssh

I want to SSH to a VM that I set up on Azure and I want to run a program on the that has an infinite while loop that scrapes some data from the internet every 10 minutes. The only problem is that I need it to run after I disconnect from the SSH session and shutdown my local machine. I have tried screen and nohup, but those don't seem to persist after I shut down my local machine. Maybe there is some other way to do it better on Azure?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the cron script or any other automation script by using the [user data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/user-data) for your virtual machines. This way, anytime the machine is reinitialized, your instructions will persist and will provision your resource accordingly.